# Through-metal-wall Ultrasound sensor imaging?

Tags: sensor, radar, ultrasound

A while ago, MIT published a paper that used a radar sensor to take a low-res image, and then they trained an AI model to convert the image into a human skeleton for through-wall human pose detection.

Problem is, radar doesn't go through metal. But ultrasound does. From a physics standpoint, does it seem likely that an ultrasound imaging device for commercial application (non medical), could be developed? Does such a device exist already?

E.g, here is an example of an output from a radar imaging sensor. The red portion corresponds to the chest of the person. The radar sensor used here is the walabot: https://walabot.com/docs/walabot-tech-brief-416

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I worked a couple of years in material testing with ultrasound (steel in my case).
On first sight I think you can not "see" through a metal wall with ultrasound.
The reason(s):

The easiest way to see this is to look at ultrasound impinging perpendicularly on an interface (steel to air in this case). The law for the reflected part of the ultrasound is then:

R = Z2 - Z1 / (Z2 - Z1)

Where Z is the acoustic impedance of the medium, wich is the product of the sound velocity and the density of that medium.

If the ultrasound comes from steel into air, then Z2 is for air:
330 m/s * 1,225 kg/m^3 = 404,25 kg/(m^2*s)
And Z1 is for steel:
5920 m / s * 7850 kg/m^3 = 46472000 kg/(m^2*s)

With this numbers, i calculate for this case that 99,99826% of the ultrasound is reflected in the steel, and only the rest is transmitted into air.
(The minus sign indicates a change of phase).

This must be taken into account at any change of the media (air to steel, steel to air, air to tissue, ...)

To make matters worse, the ultrasound will be reflected back and forth inside the steel wall and decays only slowly, making it virtually impossible to evaluate smaller ultrasound signals from elsewhere.

And there is also the Sound attenuation (i believe it is very high for ultrasound in air) wich makes this difficult.

I hope this helps